# Calling .NET 3.5+ ASMX web service or WCF service from .NET 2.0 CF

Tags: wcf, compact-framework, asmx

I'm working on project for old PDAs that run on the .NET 2.0 CF (compact framework). Right now we are using .NET 2.0 ASMX web services, but I find that severely limiting. It is missing all sorts of things like extension methods, funcs, actions, LINQ, generic data-structures like HashSet(of T), etc., that would be useful for *getting stuff done*.

Eventually we're probably going to get rid of the PDAs and replace them with some other technology. For that reason I'd like to, as best as I can, write a re-usable/RESTful-ish backend (thus WCF).

I've looked online, but haven't had much luck finding information. At the very least I'm hoping to upgrade the backend to .NET 3.5 for improved functionality. Is it possible?

Comment: We were running into some other issues that were causing problems with upgrading the back-end. Having got those resolved, I can say that the transition was painless. Yay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want the new framework libraries and c# syntax than your asmx services would work just fine on 3.5, no need to migrate to wcf.
if you want rest you should take a look at [asp.net web api](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/23/asp-net-web-api-part-1.aspx) though it is .net 4 only.